# iOS accurately calculates the UITextView height based on a string

Tags: ios, uitextview

I try to calculate the height of the UITextView adaptive string based on it.

```
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width - 2 * margin, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    textView.font = WDFontManager.regularFont(withSize: 14)
    textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: content, attributes: contentAttributes)
    textView.textContainer.widthTracksTextView = false
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))]
    //Method 1
    textView.layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textView.textContainer)
    let rect = textView.layoutManager.usedRect(for: textView.textContainer)
    let textHeight = ceil(rect.height)
    //Method 2
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.init(width: width - 2 * margin, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    let hightSize = ceil(newSize.height)
```

Under normal circumstances there is no problem.

But contains email emoticons and special characters (for example: #), this method will be calculated error.

I would like to ask if there is any more accurate way to solve this problem.

Comment: UITextView has internal scroll so as long as UITextView's scroll isnt disabled you can never get the implicit size of UITextView based on the content you set. So first set UITextView's scrollable property to false

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari   There is still an error after the setting, and the error is accidental, which occurs when the "#" ends.